# CSS: what is this weird space that I get at the bottom of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Went through every similar question on SO, but none of the solutions worked for me.

I'm building this chessboard programmatically with JS. But for some reason, I get this weird space at the bottom of the div with the "row" class. The inspector tells me the space is part of the ".row" div's content. None of the divs inside of it have this space (see screenshot). It looks the same on both Firefox and Chrome.

[The screenshot from the inspector.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsJpd.png)

Here's the HTML code. The divs with the "row" and "tile" classes are added programmatically, in case that matters:

```
<div class="board-container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="tile whiteTile" id="1,1" style="background-position: 273px 173px"><img src="./img/rook_black.png" alt="black rook"></div>
      <div class="tile blackTile" id="2,1" style="background-position: 209px -93px"><img src="./img/knight_black.png" alt="black knight"></div>
      <div class="tile whiteTile" id="3,1" style="background-position: 203px 61px"><img src="./img/bishop_black.png" alt="black bishop"></div>
      <!--- Five more squares to fill the row --->
   </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS code for the relevant classes:

```
.board-container {
    border: solid;
    width: fit-content;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5%;
}

.board-container img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.row {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: fit-content;
}

.tile {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.blackTile {
    background-image: url("img/black_tile.jpg");
    color: white;
}

.whiteTile {
    background-image: url("img/white_tile.jpg");
}
```

Also, I'm new to asking questions here, so feel free to let me know if I screwed anything up.

Comment: Could make your code into a working snippet - it needs the actual images (full URL or load them via SO) as well so we can easily see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with creating a working example.

Comment: @AHaworth Thank you, I'll look into it before posting a new question!